# Can't reload a progress bar in React after it reached 100%

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i'm building an app where i fetch data from an api and i'm trying to reload those datas automatically after minute along with a progress bar. i made a progress bar that is filling the width withoin a minute. I can't get to work the reloading after i reached the 100% automatically. this is the code for the peogress bar component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import styles from "./ProgressBar.module.css";


const Progress = ({reloading}) => {

    const [style, setStyle] = useState({});





    setInterval(() => {
        const newStyle = {
            opacity: 1,
            width: `${reloading}%`
        }

        setStyle(newStyle);
    }, 100);


    return (
        <div className={styles.progress}>
            <div className={styles.progressBar} style={style}>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Progress;
```

And this is the css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.progress {
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#dd9214, #ecc480);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -5px #F2709C, 0 2px 5px #F2709C;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 5s;
}
```

with this code my bar is filling to 100% within a minute, but i can't get how to refresh every time. Shall i use Js methods or i can achieve through css?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to that interval `let intervalRef = setInterval(()=>{ ... })` then when the loading of the progress is done you clear it `clearinterval(intervalRef)` to reset it you can just set a new style width `width:0;`

Comment: Can you expose me a snippet of the code? I'm quite new to React and i don't understand if the reference of the interval should be inside the useeffect or not

Comment: If you can put up a working code snippet with the issue, i'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wave-chyh0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You can ditch the use of `setInterval` and simply relay on transition to animation the progress https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-waterfall-2pxew

Comment: thank you very much! But if i want to reload it without clicking, can i use useEffect with conditional rendering to set the width to 0 when it reaches 100?

Comment: Yes we'll use `useEffect()` with an empty array as the second argument to run only once at the begining to initiate the progress bar, Then we'll pass a callback function to run when the progress bar is finished to reset it, I made the relevant adjustments to the previous [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lederberg-1l4ps) You can work off of this to add more features.

Comment: Perfect, that's great. I'm learning a lot from this example about Hooks. Only one last thing if i can: how can i restart in a loop the progress bar once it reaches the 100%

Comment: You can simply `setTimeout(()=>{startProgess(resetProgess)},100) ` inside reset wait `100ms` then start again it will look forever like this. you can add logic if you want to stop it at some point [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-glade-ke4tb)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was brilliant! very kind and helpful :)

Comment: but now i can't set 60s of transition :(. Every time i reload is always reload very fast

Comment: Let me see the code, i suppose you're using `ms` instead of `s` keep in mind that one  second is `1000ms` in the case of `60s` it should be `60000` or `60 * 1000` to be much more easier to understand

Comment: yeah i tried to change the setTimeout with 60000ms, but the animation is smooth and fast regarding any value. I've also tried to change the animation time in the css property but doesn't seem to work. I don't know if is better to tackle it from the Js or Css

Comment: Can you share what you tried ?